# Zipkin Integration With RabbitMQ for tracing

Tags: java, rabbitmq, zipkin, brave

I have two Microservices (Spring boot application) . For tracing I am using `<artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>` along with zipkin. Service A is producer and  send message using RabbitMQ broker. On other hand Service B is the consumer, their is  `@RabbitListener` . I want to exchange the traceId(with span details) from service A to Service B.
I have seen the [example](https://zipkin.io/pages/instrumenting.html) (using brave) but unable to integrate zipkin with rabbitMQ and trace propogation.

Can Any One please help me how to acheive this ?Any complete step-by-step and simple example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got working after spring verison updated to `5.x`
It already have `Brave Instrument for zipkin trace`